# Use 'source' command in a shortcut!

Tags: bash, shell-script, source

I have to run a bash script `GoogleDrive.sh` that changes the environment variables of `~/.profile` file. In terminal emulator `source GoogleDrive.sh` works fine, but when I put this command in desktop shortcut it says `source` is not a command and it is not recognized.
How can I run `GoogleDrive.sh` file with the `source` command without opening new terminal session?
The file `GoogleDrive.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $GOOGLE_DRIVE_ON -eq 0 ]; then
  google-drive-ocamlfuse ~/GoogleDrive
  export GOOGLE_DRIVE_ON=1
  dolphin ~/GoogleDrive
else
  fusermount -u ~/GoogleDrive
  export GOOGLE_DRIVE_ON=0
fi
```

The global variable in my `.profile` file is `GOOGLE_DRIVE_ON`.

The `source` command runs fine from the terminal emulator, but from a desktop shortcut it is not recognizable.

I use `Kali linux`.

Comment: I don't understand. Why don't you just have these in your `~/.profile` so they're read when you log in? Or are you saying they _are_ in your `~/.profile` but they are not used by your graphical shell? What operating system are you using? If Linux with a GUI, which Linux, which desktop manager and which login manager are you using? Also what is a "shortcut"? Do you mean a `.desktop` file?

Answer (score 1):

`source` isn't a file on UNIX machine. `source` is a built-in shell command. such as `export` or `shopt`.
In deept, in programming world,`exec` function run a file in your disk. it can't run a built-in shell command.